# How to use INNER/OUTER JOIN in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables which contain different types of data related to each other. the tables populate via an excel spreadsheet. I have:

```
table1            table2          table3
item_number       item_number     item_number
desc              desc            qty_sold
qty_instock       vdf_cost        upc
cost              status
```

What I'm trying to do is use a join function to show all the data as they relate to each other, except the problem is that when I run

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON  a.someColumn = b.otherColumn
INNER JOIN table3 c
ON b.anotherColumn = c.nextColumn
```

It just puts the tables side by side, If I run

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
USING(item_number)
```

It works but only joins the item number (i have no idea how to use multiple fields such as description which repeats), and for some reason I can only use the two tables when I try to add a third table (most likely being done completely wrong)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
INNER JOIN table3 c
USING(item_number)
```

I just get a syntax error.

Thanks for all the help in advance

UPDATE:

I got it working

```
SELECT *
FROM master_list a 
INNER JOIN bby_report ab USING (item_number, description)
INNER JOIN sales_report b USING (item_number)
```

Is there a way I can exclude the description from one of the tables and keep it from another one? Turns out the descriptions are not an exact match from one table to a another so it keeps returning zero results.

So to clarify keep description from table1 and leave out description from table2 while being able to JOIN the fields based on item_number

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Why would your tables relate on more than item_number? Perhaps you want to GROUP BY another field.  I can write a query that joins on multiple fields, though I'm not sure it's going to give you the expected result. What fields are you trying to relate?

Comment: basically i want a consolidated table that shows the data from all the different tables in one. item_number and description repeat in each table, so it's a bit annoying to reread the same line when it should just show the item number description qty cost etc per item

Comment: I got it thanks

SELECT *
FROM master_list a 
INNER JOIN bby_report ab USING (item_number, description)
INNER JOIN sales_report b USING (item_number)

Is there a way I can exclude the description from one of the tables and keep it from another one? Turns out the descriptions are not an exact match from one table to a another so it keeps returning zero results

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *`, just select exactly the columns you want from the tables you want.

Comment: I'm trying that but i cant seem to figure out the syntax I have:
`SELECT master_list.item_number,master_list.description,master_list.qty_stock,master_list.stnd_cost,bby_report.item_number,bby_report.vdf_cost,bby_report.sku_status,sales_report.item_number,sales_report.qty_sold
FROM master_list a
INNER JOIN bby_report ab USING (item_number)
INNER JOIN sales_report b USING (item_number)`

but it comes back and "unknown column 'master_list.item_number' in 'field list' but if it leave it as SELECT * it works (minus the extra description column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM master_list a 
INNER JOIN bby_report ab USING (item_number, description)
INNER JOIN sales_report b USING (item_number)
```